# Error in Configuration File EasyPHP and WAMP not working

Tags: php, apache, wamp, easyphp

I tried to install both EasyPHP and Wamp but when I start easyphp it starts sql normally but won't let me start apache server and gives error "Error in configuration file Edit?" but the same version works fine on my desktop computer and when I tried wamp it just crashes saying "Aestan Tray menu has encountered.. bla bla". I searched a lot on google but could not find solution to this. Kindly help me removing this error. What could be the possible cause and how could I make it working? I have tried removing Skype too.

Comment: have you tried to start it with administrator privileges?

Comment: I searched on it for long and found a solution. I was using XP and did not had .NET 3.5 framework installed. I installed it and both WAMP and EASYPHP started working. I hope it will help to somebody else.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and just fixed it.

ALl you have to do is downloading and installing [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)  and if you use a non english windows xp make sure you change the language of .net framework to the one you have on XP before you download it, otherwise it won't be installed

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows 7 there could also be error with line breaks when you add virtual host via virtual hosts manager.
I had an error with following easyphp response "Error in Apache configuration file ... Synthax error on line 12 of ... conf/inc_virtual_hosts.conf".

To fix this just open [EasyPhp Folder]\binaries\apache\conf\inc_virtual_hosts.conf and add line break where it should be!

```
# Virtual hosts<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> - error!!!
    DocumentRoot "D:/projects/...
```

Also you can check  [EasyPhp Folder]\binaries\conf_files\httpd.conf - there also can be bad synthax.